# The "Open file..." button in styles Organizer doesn't do anything in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

In Microsoft Word you can load style definitions from files to current document or some template. This article describes the process: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/1004-word-import-styles.html

Microsoft Outlook Plus 2010 has exactly the same dialog, but clicking the "Open file..." button has no effect. This is what I did:

I opened the organizer and closed file using the button:
[image: image description]

Then I tried to click *Open file...* but that has no effect:

[image: image description]

It doesn't lag the window, it's not disabled. It's just totally inactive button.

Am I missing something or is this yet another bug Microsoft will never fix?

Comment: How do you open this dialog in Outlook?

Comment: `Text formating` -> `Styles` (subtab) -> below `Change styles` there's a tiny square -> in `Styles` window click on `Manage styles` -> in the popup `Import/Export`.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue is still in Outlook 2013 and 2016.